# Complex numbers summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Sum the series $$\sum_{r=0}^n {{n}\choose{r}} \sin(\alpha +r\beta)$$

I've been using the C+jS method where C is the cosine series and S is the sine series and forming a result from there but have not been able to match the final result.

Is there any particular identities i must be aware of in order to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can rewrite it to an expansion of $(1+f)^n$ for some function $f$.

Comment: @salman, what are your result & the final one?

Answer (score 2):

Using [Euler Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html),

$$\sum_{r=0}^n {{n}\choose{r}} \sin(\alpha +r\beta)=\text{Imag}[\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nr e^{i(\alpha+r\beta)}]$$

Now, $$\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nr e^{i(\alpha+r\beta)}=e^{i\alpha}\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nr (e^{i\beta})^r=e^{i\alpha}(1+e^{i\beta})^n=e^{i\left(\alpha+\frac{\beta}2\right)}\left(e^{i\frac{\beta}2}+e^{-i\frac{\beta}2}\right)^n$$

Again as $\displaystyle e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x,e^{-ix}=\cos(-x)+i\sin(-x)=\cos x-i\sin x$

$\displaystyle\implies e^{ix}+e^{-ix}=\cdots  $

Comment: @RonGordon, sorry for the mistake, rectified

Comment: Oh, you need not apologize to me.  I wasn't misled.